# What's the best way to convert fabric model with _ (underscores) to a convector model or plain json/object

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, convector

what's the best way to convert fabric model with _ (underscores) to a convector/json object

when I receive a frabric model I'm receiving a model with underscores ex

```
JSON.stringify(participant, undefined, 2)
"{
  "_id": "gov",
  "_identities": [
    {
      "fingerprint": "75:7B:3F:16:C8:0F:FA:15:4A:B9:7D:2B:AE:85:76:1F:75:A3:C5:05",
      "status": true
    }
  ],
  "_msp": "org1MSP",
  "_name": "Big Government",
  "_type": "io.worldsibu.examples.participant"
}"
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

@diestrin: wrap the response you get in the model itself, like: new Participant(participant).toJSON()
or even better, before sending it in the controller, send it like a JSON already

Answer (score 0):

we must use convector models to do the conversion,

@diestrin: that's the one that has the logic to correctly remove the _ of the props

above we have a method that convert fabric to convector model, used in a graphql api, with typegraphql

```js
  async findOneById(id: string): Promise<Participant> {
    try {
      // get fabric model with _props
      const participant: Participant = await ParticipantControllerBackEnd.get(id);
      // convert fabric model to convector module _props
      const participantModel = new ParticipantConvectorModel(participant).toJSON();
      // trick: must return convector model as a graphql model, to prevent property conversion problems
      return (participantModel as Participant);
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

> Note for comment lines